# Retrieving a single value from belongsToMany relationship in blade template

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have created a model with a belongsToMany relationship. The model is Vendor and the relationship with Location. So, in my blade template, I would normally do something like this:

```
@foreach ($vendor->locations as $loc)
{{$loc-id}}
@endforeach
```

However, I would like to simply json_encode only the id values for each of the locations. If possible, I would like to do so without creating a loop. So, I know I can do this:

```
{{json_encode($vendor->locations)}}
```

But as you can guess, this dumps out JSON data of all of the fields in the locations table.

I know I can modify my relationship to only include the ID fields, but I do not want to do this because I want to use the relationship elsewhere.

Is there a way to just grab the ID fields using something like:

```
{{json_encode($vendor->locations->id)}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pluck the 'id' and convert it directly to json.

```
{{ $vendor->locations->pluck('id')->toJson() }}
```

This requires that `$vendor->locations` is a Collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel's pluck and json methods:

```
{{ $vendor->locations->pluck('id')->toJson() }}
```

You can refer to the documentation for more information:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-tojson